# How to select json response item with spaces

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript so this might be a naive question. I have following json response from the server. I want to select the values of Alpha, Bravo, Charlie and Delta.

```
data = {"Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)":{"Alpha":33245.0,"Bravo":26618.0,"Charlie":22376.0,"Delta":15831.0}}
```

I can select values in the console by doing `data["Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)"]`. However when I try this in JavaScript (code editor) by doing `console.log(data["Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)"])`, it returns `null`.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I try this in JavaScript (code editor)"?

Comment: what does `console.log(data)` outputs in JavaScript (code editor)?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```js
data = {
  "Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)": {
    "Alpha": 33245.0,
    "Bravo": 26618.0,
    "Charlie": 22376.0,
    "Delta": 15831.0
  }
}

console.log(`
  ${data['Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)'].Alpha}
  ${data['Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)'].Bravo}
  ${data['Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)'].Charlie}
  ${data['Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)'].Delta}  
`);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you are looking for values of Alpha ,Bravo. if yes,Try this

```js
var data = {"Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)":{"Alpha":33245.0,"Bravo":26618.0,"Charlie":22376.0,"Delta":15831.0}}

var selectedVal = Object.keys(data).map(function (prop) {
   return Object.keys(data[prop]).map(function(val){
      return data[prop][val]
   })

})

console.log(selectedVal,"selectedVal")
```

Answer (score -2):

There are many ways to access object properties, one of which is listed below:

First you extract keys using `Object.keys` which returns array of keys to you of a given object. You then iterate through each array item which is `key` of the given object and access using object property that key. Solutions like this would avoid all the potential typos in accessing key naming.

Its not a comprehensive solution to cover all edge cases but with keys having spaces, these is pretty good technique to cover all the bases. One thing to note here is key access is not in sorted order.

```js
var data = {
  "Agent Contribution (Incl Rev)": {
    "Alpha": 33245.0,
    "Bravo": 26618.0,
    "Charlie": 22376.0,
    "Delta": 15831.0
  }
}

Object.keys(data).map(obj => {
  console.log(data[obj]);
  console.log(data[obj].Alpha);
  console.log(data[obj].Bravo);
});
```